# Ignore fields in Jackson JSON parser?

Tags: json, jackson

I am working on this JSON parsing use case where I get stuck because of some unwanted property value in my response JSON. Please find below Request JSON :

```
{"isComplete": false}
```

My Java code looks something like below:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    @JasonProperty("isComplete")
    private Boolean complete;

    public Boolean getComplete() {
       return this.complete;
    }

    public void setComplete(Boolean complete) {
       this.complete = complete;
    }
}
```

After performing some business logic I am changing the flag value to "true". But response I am getting is bit odd as shown below:

```
{
   "isComplete": true,
   "complete": true  --> How to ignore this field?
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem you should annotate the getter and setter, not the private variable.

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    private Boolean complete;

    @JsonProperty("isComplete")
    public Boolean getComplete() {
        return this.complete;
    }

    @JsonProperty("isComplete")
    public void setComplete(Boolean complete) {
        this.complete = complete;
    }
}
```